# Exporting Big Layout to PDF Crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, layouts, windows-10

I'm trying to export a large orthomosaic layout to PDF.  Double-sized A0 (or 2A0) works and prints beautifully.  Now need to print it larger (i.e. 2.6m x 2.3m for a wall), but need it as a PDF to do so.

QGIS crashes with about 16 "Uh-oh! QGIS Unexpectedly Ended" windows.
Always crashes when the PDF size hits 213,574KB, so not sure if it's a file size limitation or whether there's something in the layout that QGIS doesn't like.

Exporting the same layout to TIFF crashes QGIS almost immediately.

Running QGIS 3.16.6 Hannover under Windows 10 Pro on a x64-based PC with 32GB RAM.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried determining which layer causes the issue by turning them on/off?

Comment: Hi Erik, Yes - just done some experiments on my layout and datasets. My export map scale is 1:250.  If I change it to smaller than 1:500, the export works. Anything between 1:250 and 1:500 then the export fails (even though it works fine at 1:400 scale on a Double A0 export).  The main layer is a 1cm resolution orthophoto.  It's silly that I can export it at a larger scale on a smaller piece of paper.